# Creating Azure Virtual Machine from Managed Image, Credentials required

Tags: azure

We create our VM images via Packer for Azure.  Our machine images already have all of the credentials and configuration required for their management.

What is the reasoning regarding creating a virtual machine in Azure, it is required to specify an Admin User with a password or an SSH Key?

I would like to not specify either if possible. If impossible, is there any recommendation as to which or what to do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to créate a VM and not specify the username\password (or ssh key). As for the second part of the question - I dont really understand it, sorry.